# Unexpected character after line continuation character error when i try to print

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a calculator visual interface with text characters but when i try to print the lines I get this error.

```
L1="┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓\n┃ ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ ┃"
LS="              "
LL="┃ ┃"
L2="┃ ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫ ┃\n┃ ┣━┳━┳━┳━━━┳━━━┫ ┃\n┃ ┃7┃8┃9┃DEL┃A.C┃ ┃"
L3="┃ ┣━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━━━┫ ┃\n┃ ┃4┃5┃6┃ x ┃ ÷ ┃ ┃\n┃ ┣━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━━━┫ ┃"
L4="┃ ┃1┃2┃3┃ + ┃ - ┃ ┃\n┃ ┣━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━━━┫ ┃\n┃ ┃0┃.┃ ┃ANS┃ = ┃ ┃"
L5="┃ ┗━┻━┻━┻━━━┻━━━┛ ┃\n┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛"
print(L1,\nLL,LS,LL,\nLL,LS,LL,\nL2,\nL3,\nL4,\nL5)
```

this is what my code looks like and idk how to fix it, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: `print(L1,"\n",LL,LS,LL,"\n",LL,LS,LL,"\n",L2,"\n",L3,"\n",L4,"\n",L5)` - you might also codsider using `print( .... , sep="")` or simply put all lines into a big list and do `print(*bigList,sep="\n")`

Comment: make it a function that also formats the result into it:  `def printCalc(text):` && `print(*["┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓","┃ ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ ┃","┃ ┃{:>13}┃ ┃".format(text),"┃ ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫ ┃","┃ ┣━┳━┳━┳━━━┳━━━┫ ┃","┃ ┃7┃8┃9┃DEL┃A.C┃ ┃","┃ ┣━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━━━┫ ┃","┃ ┃4┃5┃6┃ x ┃ ÷ ┃ ┃","┃ ┣━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━━━┫ ┃","┃ ┃1┃2┃3┃ + ┃ - ┃ ┃","┃ ┣━╋━╋━╋━━━╋━━━┫ ┃","┃ ┃0┃.┃ ┃ANS┃ = ┃ ┃","┃ ┗━┻━┻━┻━━━┻━━━┛ ┃","┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛"],sep="\n")` && call by `printCalc("4+2 = 42")`

Answer (score 1):

use "\n", in your print instead of \n, so: print(L1,"\n", LL,LS,LL,"\n", LL,LS,LL,"\n", L2,"\n", L3,"\n", L4,"\n", L5)

Comment: well yeah but then each comma adds a space before the next line.

Comment: no, it won't. You print variables here that contain the strings.

Comment: it will - unless you specify `print( ... stuff ... , sep="")`

Comment: nevermind, it worked when i replaced the commas with plus signs, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Why not do multiple print statements and also remove the `\n` usage like so:

```
def print_calc(text):
    print("┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓")
    print("┃ ┏━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ ┃")
    print("┃ ┃{:>13}┃ ┃".format(text))
    print("┃ ┣━━━━━━━━━━━━━┫ ┃")
    print("┃ ┣━┳━┳━┳━━━┳━━━┫ ┃")
    print("┃ ┃7┃8┃9┃DEL┃A.C┃ ┃")
    # ... and so on ...
```

Comment: I want to use that print later as I'm going to clean the screen and print it again as you press a number. so that wont work

Comment: Ok I've put it in a function which allows you to print only when you need it. And let's you put a variable into the 'screen'. Check out my updated solution. :)